# AnyLogic: Return Name of Current Block

Tags: anylogic, agent-based-modeling

Hi I am using AnyLogic's Process Modelling Library.

I have a DB named dbsewing06 that has a record of all the service delay times
[ sewing (Name of Service) | sum_ct (Delay time) ]

For a service, I use the following code to get Delay time:
selectFrom(dbsewing06)
    .where(dbsewing06.sewing.eq(SEW_06_16.getName()))
    .uniqueResult(dbsewing06.sum_ct, double.class)

SEW_06_16 here is the name of the Service in question.

However, I want to use the name from of Block dynamically. Is there any way to do this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89dGn.png)

Comment: Aren't you already doing it dynamically? What do you mean?

But I guess this is a potential answer:
instead of SEW_06_16.getName()
do
self.getName()

who knows.. I don't understand the question really :P

Comment: Oh my goodness, yes it is self.getName(). Thank you so much. I need to stop modelling and get some sleep!